How to setup java spring boot application to send message to Azure service bus Topic
I am asking this question here to get help from Microsoft or community
I want to send messages to a topic using spring boot application
The azure page is service bus
My app properties
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.namespace=<<some name>> 
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.entity-name=<<some topic>> 

spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.processor.subscription-name=<<somesub>> 

spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.entity-type=topic


Error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Subscription cannot be
null.

My code has the dependency management , spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus
The config class as mentioned in the pages - ServiceBusProcessorClientConfiguration
and the bootstrap class - ServiceBusQueueApplication
(I prefer to have a sender and a receiver in 2 different apps. Not like PING-PONG in the same program. May be I want to see/consume message in a logic app )
what am I missing ? How to send message with properties (see attached)
EDIT:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceBusReceiverClientBuilder' defined in class path resource [com/azure/spring/cloud/autoconfigure/implementation/servicebus/AzureServiceBusConsumerClientConfiguration$NoneSessionConsumerClientConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusClientBuilder$ServiceBusReceiverClientBuilder]: Factory method 'serviceBusReceiverClientBuilder' threw exception with message: Subscription cannot be null.
    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusClientBuilder$ServiceBusReceiverClientBuilder]: Factory method 'serviceBusReceiverClientBuilder' threw exception with message: Subscription cannot be null.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Subscription cannot be null.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:172) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at com.azure.spring.cloud.service.implementation.servicebus.factory.ServiceBusReceiverClientBuilderFactory.configureService(ServiceBusReceiverClientBuilderFactory.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-azure-service-5.11.0.jar:5.11.0]
    at com.azure.spring.cloud.service.implementation.servicebus.factory.ServiceBusReceiverClientBuilderFactory.configureService(ServiceBusReceiverClientBuilderFactory.java:15) ~[spring-cloud-azure-service-5.11.0.jar:5.11.0]
    at com.azure.spring.cloud.core.implementation.factory.AbstractAzureServiceClientBuilderFactory.build(AbstractAzureServiceClientBuilderFactory.java:128) ~[spring-cloud-azure-core-5.11.0.jar:5.11.0]
    at com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.implementation.servicebus.AzureServiceBusConsumerClientConfiguration$NoneSessionConsumerClientConfiguration.serviceBusReceiverClientBuilder(AzureServiceBusConsumerClientConfiguration.java:70) ~[spring-cloud-azure-autoconfigure-5.11.0.jar:5.11.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

POM:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>azureservicebus</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>azureservicebus</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.11.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



can you share the full stacktrace and pom please ?

@Kris Swat I tried a sample Spring boot project code to send messages to Azure Service Bus through Postman.

@DasariKamali which code you have used? spring boot? Also confirm that you used filters to make sure a message goes to a specific subscriber based on message

@KrisSwat Yes, I used Spring boot to send message to Azure Service Bus Topic with a Subscription.

@DasariKamali do you know what is wrong with the above code ?

@KrisSwat You haven't shared your code in the question. If possible, can you share it so I can check it?

@KrisSwat The error message indicates an issue with creating the ServiceBusReceiverClientBuilder bean due to a null subscription name. This error is likely occurring during the initialization of the Azure Service Bus receiver client

@KrisSwat Verify that the servicebus.subscription property is correctly set with the name of your Service Bus subscription.

@DasariKamali the configuration I used is in the question . Give a comprehensive answer if possible. Are you using example code or propreitory code that you can not share ?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Microsoft has provided an answer and updated the documentation
Add this property and the service bus topic works
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.consumer.subscription-name=<same as processor subscription>

and about filter messages, send data with application properties and the rule works
message.getApplicationProperties().put("status", data.getStatus());
senderClient.sendMessage(message);


I tried the sample Spring Boot code below to send messages to the Azure Service Bus Topic.
Code :
ServiceBusConfig.java :
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusClientBuilder;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusProcessorClient;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusSenderClient;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.models.ServiceBusReceiveMode;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ServiceBusConfig {

    @Value("${servicebus.connectionString}")
    private String connectionString;

    @Value("${servicebus.topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Value("${servicebus.subscription}")
    private String subscription;

    public ServiceBusProcessorClient serviceBusProcessorClient() {
        return new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .processor()
                .topicName(topic)
                .subscriptionName(subscription)
                .receiveMode(ServiceBusReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK)
                .processMessage(context -> {
                    System.out.printf("Received message from %s, %s: %s%n", topic, subscription, context.getMessage().getBody().toString());
                    context.complete();
                })
                .processError(context -> {
                    System.err.printf("Error occurred: %s%n", context.getException());
                })
                .buildProcessorClient();
    }

    public ServiceBusSenderClient serviceBusSenderClient() {
        return new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .sender()
                .topicName(topic)
                .buildClient();
    }
}

ServiceBusController.java :
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusMessage;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusProcessorClient;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusSenderClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ServiceBusController {

    private final ServiceBusProcessorClient serviceBusProcessorClient;
    private final ServiceBusSenderClient serviceBusSenderClient;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceBusController(ServiceBusConfig serviceBusConfig) {
        this.serviceBusProcessorClient = serviceBusConfig.serviceBusProcessorClient();
        this.serviceBusSenderClient = serviceBusConfig.serviceBusSenderClient();
    }

    @PostMapping("/sendMessage")
    public String sendMessage(@RequestBody String message) {
        serviceBusSenderClient.sendMessage(new ServiceBusMessage(message));
        return "Message sent to Service Bus topic: " + message;
    }
}

pom.xml :
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
          <version>5.12.0</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
          <version>7.16.0</version>
     </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
</dependencies>

application.properties :
servicebus.connectionString=<connec_string>
servicebus.topic=<topic_name>
servicebus.subscription=<subscription_name>

Local Output :


Postman Output :
I sent the message to the Azure Service Bus using Postman, as follows:
http://localhost:8080/sendMessage

{
"message": "Hi Kamali.Welcome!"
}


Azure Portal :
The message was sent successfully to the Azure Service Bus, as shown below.


I did not use this because microsoft mentioned this statement "The following list shows reasons why this code isn't flexible or graceful:"  The recommendation s to use "Fortunately, building the client beans by yourself isn't necessary with Spring Cloud Azure. Instead, you can directly inject the beans and use the configuration properties that you're already familiar with to configure Service Bus."

@KrisSwat Ok, will try another code and let you know.

@KrisSwat Updated the code without Bean and can send messages to Azure Service BUs Topic.
